# Calculate Row Means for Different Number of Columns per Group R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` with 422 columns and I need to calculate the mean across rows but the columns need to be grouped in a certain, unequal order. Sample data below:

```
library(data.table)
m <- data.table(ID = LETTERS, GENE = paste("gene", 1:26, sep = ""), SAMPLE = paste(1, "A", sep = ""), REGION = "UNITED_STATES")

for (x in 1:418) set(m, i = NULL, j = paste("RUN", x, sep = ""), value = rnorm(nrow(m)))
```

The columns need to be grouped in the following order:

```
breaks <- c(25, 25, 25, 20, 40, 40, 40, 32, 25, 25, 25, 20, 20, 20, 20, 16)
```

So the final table will be a `data.table` with the first four 'info' columns followed by 16 columns each with the average from those breaks above. New table's 16 columns are the mean of columns (from the original data) 1-25, 26-50, 51-75, 76-95, etc. I am aware of how to calculate the row means across all columns, I thought there was some way to do it with `.SDcols` but I don't think you can make groups the way I'm trying to.

```
m[,.(Mean = rowMeans(.SD)), keyby = .(ID, GENE, SAMPLE, REGION)]
```

Also I'm prepared to make those breaks by hand depending on the methods proposed, 1:25, 26:50, etc. but it would be nice to do it in R.

Comment: You've probably heard this before, but: it's not advisable to do things rowwise with a data.table or data.frame. If you're amenable to switching to long-format data, then something like `melt(m, id=1:4)[, rown := as.integer(sub("RUN","", variable))][, mean(value), by=cut(rown, cumsum(breaks))]` might work.